# Disable AngularJS dropdown multiselect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive to disable the angularjs dropdown multiselect, this directive working properly when change the checkbox but it's not working when init the control, I want to disable the dropdown by the value that is passed to the  directive when start the controller.

that's the directive:

```
var FormModule = angular.module('FormModule', []);
FormModule.directive('ngDropdownMultiselectDisabled', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var $btn;
            $btn = $element.find('button');
            return $scope.$watch($attrs.ngDropdownMultiselectDisabled, function (newVal) {
                return $btn.attr('disabled', newVal);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and that's the div of the dropdown:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input id="chkHasParent" type="checkbox" class="form-control"
           ng-model="property.HasParent" ng-checked="property.HasParent==true" />
    <label for="chkHasParent" class="lblCheck">Has Parent</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>Parent Property</label>
    <div id="ddlParentProperty" ng-dropdown-multiselect=""
         options="Properties" selected-model="parentPropertyModel"
         extra-settings="settingParentProperty"
         ng-dropdown-multiselect-disabled="!property.HasParent">
    </div>
</div>
```

and thats the [docs](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) of the Angular js dropdown multiselect if anyone does not know it.

Comment: Not sure about this as I've never used this package.  If no one seems to be able to help you can always leave a comment / question on the GitHub Issue where you found this solution:  https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/30.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $scope.hasParentChange = function hasParentChange(hasParent) {
                    if (hasParent != null) {
                        if (hasParent == false) {
                            document.getElementById("ddlParentProperty").getElementsByTagName('button')[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                        }
                        else {
                            document.getElementById("ddlParentProperty").getElementsByTagName('button')[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("ddlParentProperty").getElementsByTagName('button')[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                    }

                }

                angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                    $scope.hasParentChange($scope.property.HasParent)
                });
```